# A strange stuff of my gVim and emmet plugin

Tags: vim, emmet

I install gvim and its emmet plugin(win7 64bit,default _vimrc),but has some problem with it.

I found a strange stuff in my gVim. when I expand at a letter, my vim will pick one letter from the line next to the current line and push to the current cursor point. like this:

```
body { c| }
#wrap{position:relative....
```

(cursor at '|')when expand, it will pick the 'o' in 'position' to c and so problem comes.

but if I back to normal mode and expand,all will run perfect.

What a devil! If the next position of cursor in the next line is blank, the expand action will run with no mistake.

I just use vim a week, can somebody tell me the possible reason of this?

Comment: As this seems to be a problem with the Emmet plugin, it's best to ask on its issue tracker, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I asked, but he has no this problem...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bad installation but another thing seems off: Emmet's default leader combo is `<C-y>` so, if anything, Vim should insert a character from the line *above* (`:help i_ctrl-y`) not from the line *below* (`:help i_ctrl-e`).

I'd suggest insisting on the issue tracker.

Comment: I think your comment is very close to the real reason,I'll contact to the plugin author and tell him about this